# Javascript is performing a function somewhere that it's not supposed to

Tags: javascript, html

So, I've got this toggleImage function:

```
    var imgName
function toggleImage() {
    image = document.querySelector("img")
    if (imgName == "business") {
        image.src = "assignment-resources/images/business.jpg";
        imgName = "sports"
    }
    else {
        image.src = "assignment-resources/images/sports.jpg";
        imgName = "business"
    }

}
```

It worked fine, until I set up this toggleModal function:

```
    var modalOpen
function toggleModal(){

    if (modalOpen == "yes"){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalOpen = "no"
    }

    else{
        modal.style.display = "none";
        modalOpen = "yes"
    }
```

Now, the toggleImage function is being performed in the modal, rather than changing the image that it's supposed to change, even though they're both completely seperate.

Modal code:

```
        <section class = "modal" id = "modal">
        <section class = "modal-content">
                <img src = "assignment-resources/images/razgriz.jpg">
        </section>
        </section>
```

Image section code:

```
<section class= "picture"><img src = "assignment-
resources/images/business.jpg"></section>
```

Basically, I've got a swapImage button that's supposed to swap the image in the "picture" section, and it was working fine, until I added the toggleModal function.

Now, even if the modal isn't showing, the swapImage function changes the image within the modal, rather than the "picture" section.

Apologies if I'm not very clear, I'm still learning all this.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be more specific — especially about *where* these functions are called.  And also, what do you mean by, 'function is being performed in the modal'. Do you mean there's an image in the modal that's being toggled?

Comment: I've edited my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific with your `document.querySelector("img")`. This will return the *first* image it finds. In your case it sounds like it's finding the image in the modal.

With your HTML you can select more specifically with something like:

```
document.querySelector("section.picture img")
```

This will get the first image that is a descendant of the first `section` with `class=picture`. Of course, you might want to add IDs or something else to make the exact selection you want.